# Kde neon stuck on splash screen

Tags: linux, kde, freeze

I just recently bought a new laptop "Hp pavilion power 15-cb012no" and I was trying to install KDE Neon on it. The laptop has a ssd and a hdd. I was trying to install linux on the hdd, since the ssd is so small and windows is already installed on it. I got to boot the system form a flash drive and tried installing kde. It installed successfully but when I try to boot it up from the hdd, it will not boot. It will either get stuck at the loading splash screen or sometimes it will load and I will get to type my password, but when I type my password and hit enter, the splash screen appears again and then freezes.

I also noticed that after the installation, I couldn't restart the laptop without forcing it to shut down by holding down the power button. It just froze and I waited for like 5 minutes but it did nothing.

Comment: Try switching to a text console and back into Xorg and see if that un-freezes KDE. I had this issue a while ago, when KDE would freeze all the time, including on and after the spash screen, and using this method unfroze it enough to uninstall KDE and install Mate.